# Command to import data from file

Tags: matlab, matlab-load

I'm using MATLAB to organize IR camera measurement data and I'd like to work more efficient than now.

The SW for IR camera exports data organised in columns

```
Some text
488.875 1300110589.875  2   14.3.2011 14:49:49.875  0   1
488.875 1300110590.156  2   14.3.2011 14:49:50.156  0   2
488.875 1300110590.671  2   14.3.2011 14:49:50.671  0   3
488.875 1300110590.953  2   14.3.2011 14:49:50.953  0   4
488.875 1300110591.234  2   14.3.2011 14:49:51.234  0   5
```

I can load it manually, I can also use `load -ascii foo.bar` but first way is long because of neverending clicking, second one is annoyg because when using `load -ascii` I have to remove first line with "some text" in it.
Right now I have to edit all the files, load them, extract first column and merge them into a matrix.

So my question is: Is there any command, or command routine, that can import this file structure without any need to edit it? I just want data from first column (It's not such a waste of time editing one file)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) is the way to go. For example:

```
fid = fopen('foo.bar','r');
data = textscan(fid,'%f %*f %*d %*s %*s %*d %*d','HeaderLines',1);
fclose(fid);
data = data{1};  %# Remove cell array encapsulation
```

This will skip one header line in the file and ignore the data in columns 2 through 7, returning only the data from the first column in the N-by-1 array `data`.